# Have Python Save A Website As XML to Desktop File

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to do something very simple and just can't get it to work. I have spent a few hours on it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

In Firefox, I have saved a "predictit" webpage
(https://www.predictit.org/api/marketdata/markets/4366) as an .xml file on my desktop.

I can successfully use this file as follows:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(r'C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\4366.xml')
root = tree.getroot()    
print(root[5][0][7].text)
```

My question is how do I get Python to save the website as an xml file  on my desktop?
Because I am sure the answer is so simple, I won't document my failures trying requests, urllib, open, write, etc.

Thanks so much for your time and efforts.

Ellie The Good Dog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
url = "https://www.predictit.org/api/marketdata/markets/4366"
res = requests.get(url)
if res.status_code == 200:
    with open('filename.xml', 'w') as f:
        f.write(res.text)
```

I think that should do what you want.

Comment: Thank you sashaaero. I appreciate it.  My problem is then that if I run the code I originally pasted on that Python-saved file...it fails.  When I run ET.parse on the file that Python saved, I get: "ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0."  That is really my problem. Any ideas at that point?  Thanks!

Comment: @EllieTheGoodDog Yeah, I see. This website returns JSON for this request. Are you okay with JSON or you need XML?

Comment: Hmmm...not sure.  XML ideally as I know how to access that.  But if that is not possible, I would be fine to try JSON.  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: It is possible, but i'm not sure which headers you should set. Default doesn't work for me. Also work with JSON is easy. You can just `data = json.loads(text)` and you have a dictionary of given data.

Comment: Got it - I saw another posts that explains json.loads.  I did not recognize that they curly brackets was json.  Thanks for pointing that out!  I should be able to figure it out from here.  Thanks so much.